# Start of Shabbos

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat, rishonim, kabbalat-hatorah

I believe someone asked a question on this site regarding the which day Shabbos starts I.E. Friday night or Shabbos Day.

Some answers quoted machlokes Rishonim that before matan torah Shabbos started on the day I.E Saturday could be Alos Hashachar  and after MT Shabbos started Friday night.

Could someone let me know in finding that Machlokes or direct me to the question that was asked on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I think I may have find the answer that I was looking for:

The link is here[rabbis change day and night](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47635/is-there-really-evidence-that-the-rabbis-changed-the-days-beginning-from-sunris/47637#47637)

And another link here [https://booksnthoughts.com/why-women-must-start-shabbat-before-men/[enter](https://booksnthoughts.com/why-women-must-start-shabbat-before-men/%5Benter) link description here][2](https://booksnthoughts.com/why-women-must-start-shabbat-before-men/)

Link here[enter link description here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71760/did-the-rashbam-practice-what-he-preached-regarding-shabbat?rq=1#comment227500_71769)